# Redshift performance on columns with different compression (encoding) types

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Is there a significant difference in performance of joins when the encodings of the columns we join with are different?

(e.g. join on a.field1=b.field1, where a.field1 is varchar with LZO encoding and b.field2 is varchar with bytedict encoding)

Or does redshift decompress data and none of this matters?

Answer (score 0):

I wondering about that issue in the past and i didn't find any explanation from Amazon about that , but i tested that and i didn't find any performance differences,
but if you want to improve your joins performances i find out that define the join column as a distkey very useful